# Running Comparison Tests in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, version-control

I'm working on my copy of project XYZ; and Bob is working on his copy of project XYZ as well.

Bobs project has a few minute changes than mine; only I don't know where they are.

Other than using github, how can I run and compare my folder against someone else's, and see all of the differences between the two? Is there a way to do this in terminal locally?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are in Linux run this command

```
$ diff dir1 dir2
```

This will show the list of differences between folders including difference in file contents.